# Adding subview designed for iPhone 7 looks big in smaller iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xib

I have a problem when I add a Subview.

I have a main xib that works ok, and in it, I want insert a subview from another xib.

[interface builder of subview xib with constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJUAI.png)

[what I see in simulator in smaller iPhones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhrzJ.png)

Both xib are designed for iPhone 7plus, I see them OK in iPhone 7plus simulator, but when I choose SE for example, I see the main xib perfect (in all iPhones), and the second subview xib I import in code, looks bigger than the screen.

(If in Interface builder, for de subview xib I choose iPhone SE, then I see it correct in iPhone SE simulator, but smaller in iPhone 7plus simulator)

I tried lot of constants with auto layout, but doesn't work. I think it must be a problem o code when I use insertSubview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Crea vista Informacion
    [self creaVistaInformacion];
}

    -(void) creaVistaInformacion{
    UIView *viewInfoNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AvisosInformacion" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [[self view] insertSubview:viewInfoNib atIndex:0];
}
```

If you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Either you need to set the frame of your viewInfoNib depending on the bounds of the parent view.
But better practice would be to create constraints for your new subview that would make the view resizable depending on the device

Comment: I have edit screenshot where you can see the constraints. They work ok if I use them in main xib, but they don't when I use in the second xib that I add with insertSubview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have internal constraint in the view described by your nib, but you do not have constraint external to the nib that position and size it in your superview (witch is the view of your view controller).

An example using frames :

```
UIView *viewInfoNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AvisosInformacion" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
// Setting the right frame (will not work if the view is resized)
[viewInfoNib setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[[self view] insertSubview:viewInfoNib atIndex:0];
```

An example using constraints :

```
UIView *viewInfoNib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AvisosInformacion" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[[self view] insertSubview:viewInfoNib atIndex:0];

// Create here the constraints (will work even if the view is resized)
// You can create then with the visual format for example, check http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first example using frames worked perfect, now I see everything ok in each iPhone.